# Python connection to AWS MySQL DB - "Error connecting to AWS: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'user'"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Happy Easter! I have a problem connecting to a MySQL Database on AWS. 
Code is as below:

```
try:   
    # ***NB*** Need to run pip install pymysql in the Anaconda Prompt for this part to work. 
    REGION = "eu-west-1c"
    username = "username_here"
    password = "password_here!!!"
    rds_host = "rds_host_here.rds.amazonaws.com"
    db_name = "database-1"
    port=int(3306)

    connection = pymysql.connect(rds_host, port, user=username, passwd=password, db=db_name, charset='utf8mb4')
```

When I run this, I am getting an error: 
"Error connecting to AWS: **init**() got multiple values for argument 'user'".

Anyone got any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Are there any spaces or oddities in your actual username? Hard to debug without the actual value (I get the security concern).

Comment: No - just admin, I suppose no need to keep that a secret :)

Comment: No I can't see how it would be - its a stand-alone piece of code, no relationship to any other part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the second positional argument for `pymysql.connect()` is the user value, but you're providing it as a kwarg afterwards. If using kwargs, it should instead be

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host=rds_host, port=port, user=username, passwd=password, db=db_name, charset='utf8mb4')
```

For mixing positional args with kwargs, you can do

```
connection = pymysql.connect(rds_host, username, password, db_name, port=port, charset='utf8mb4')
```

Here is a link for reference: [PyMySQL Docs](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html)

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your help here - that has fixed that error (so I will mark it as the solution!) but I now have a new error : "Error connecting to AWS: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '<name_here>.amazonaws.com' (timed out)").

Comment: @user3600952 Looks like a network error - either there's a firewall issue (on your computer or maybe you need to update your security group within AWS console) or the DB is unreachable/down.

Comment: Thanks SteveK - yes it turned out that I needed to create an outbound rule on my machine, and to update the security group to listen on 3306. I marked the above as the solution - it was part of it anyway! Thanks for your help!